# How to use PHP proxy for CORS?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to use a weather API which returns the data in xml format. I was using a third-party proxy server to get around CORS issues but that service is no longer running. I am using jquery/ajax to get the data like this:

```
function getMetarToTable(){
    var stationt="KJFK";
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'proxy.php',
    crossDomain: true,
    data: {'stationString': stationt},
    datatype: "xml",
    headers: {
        'X-Proxy-URL': 'https://www.aviationweather.gov/adds/dataserver_current/httpparam?datasource=metars&requestType=retrieve&format=xml&mostRecentForEachStation=constraint&hoursBeforeNow=1.25',
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log('Error: ' + errorThrown);
    },
       success: function(xml) {
       $("#metarweatherpage").html('');
       $(xml).find('METAR').each(function(){

      var sRawtext = $(this).find('raw_text').text();
      var sStationid = $(this).find('station_id').text();
      $("#metarweatherpage").append('<p><h2>'+sStationid+'</h2></p><p>'+sRawtext+'</p>');

     });
     },

    });

};
```

**PHP - proxy.php**

```
    <?php
    if( ! isset($whitelist))
        $whitelist = [];
    if( ! isset($curl_maxredirs))
        $curl_maxredirs = 10;
    if( ! isset($curl_timeout))
        $curl_timeout = 30;
    // Get stuff
    $headers = getallheaders();
    $method = __('REQUEST_METHOD', $_SERVER);
    $url = __('X-Proxy-Url', $headers);
    $cookie = __('X-Proxy-Cookie', $headers);
    // Check that we have a URL
    if( ! $url)
        http_response_code(400) and exit("X-Proxy-Url header missing");
    // Check that the URL looks like an absolute URL
    if( ! parse_url($url, PHP_URL_SCHEME))
        http_response_code(403) and exit("Not an absolute URL: $url");
    // Check referer hostname
    if( ! parse_url(__('Referer', $headers), PHP_URL_HOST) == $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])
        http_response_code(403) and exit("Invalid referer");
    // Check whitelist, if not empty
    if( ! empty($whitelist) and ! array_reduce($whitelist, 'whitelist', [$url, false]))
        http_response_code(403) and exit("Not whitelisted: $url");
    // Remove ignored headers and prepare the rest for resending
    $ignore = ['Cookie', 'Host', 'X-Proxy-URL'];
    $headers = array_diff_key($headers, array_flip($ignore));
    if($cookie)
        $headers['Cookie'] = $cookie;
    foreach($headers as $key => &$value)
        $value = "$key: $value";
    // Init curl
    $curl = curl_init();
    do
    {
        // Set generic options
        curl_setopt_array($curl, [
                CURLOPT_URL => $url,
                CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
                CURLOPT_HEADER => TRUE,
                CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => $curl_timeout,
                CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => TRUE,
                CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => $curl_maxredirs,
            ]);
        // Method specific options
        switch($method)
        {
            case 'HEAD':
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, TRUE);
                break;
            case 'GET':
                break;
            case 'PUT':
            case 'POST':
            case 'DELETE':
            default:
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, file_get_contents('php://input'));
                break;
        }
        // Perform request
        ob_start();
        curl_exec($curl) or http_response_code(500) and exit(curl_error($curl));
        $out = ob_get_clean();
        // HACK: If for any reason redirection doesn't work, do it manually...
        $url = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_REDIRECT_URL);
    }
    while($url and --$maxredirs > 0);
    // Get curl info and close handler
    $info = curl_getinfo($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    // Remove any existing headers
    header_remove();
    // Use gz, if acceptable
    ob_start('ob_gzhandler');
    // Output headers
    $header = substr($out, 0, $info['header_size']);
    array_map('header', explode("\r\n", $header));
    // And finally the body
    echo substr($out, $info['header_size']);
    // Helper functions
    function __($key, array $array, $default = null)
    {
        return array_key_exists($key, $array) ? $array[$key] : $default;
    }
    function whitelist($carry, $item)
    {
        static $url;
        if(is_array($carry))
        {
            $url = parse_url($carry[0]);
            $url['raw'] = $carry[0];
            $carry = $carry[1];
        }
        // Equals the full URL
        if(isset($item[0]))
            return $carry or $url['raw'] == $item[0];

        // Regex matches the full URL
        if(isset($item['regex']))
            return $carry or preg_match($item['regex'], $url['raw']);
        // Select components matches same components in the URL
        return $carry or $item == array_intersect_key($url, $item);
    }
```

I get a 400 Bad Request error and the response is "X-Proxy-Url header missing".

Answer (score 0):

Bit late to the party, but it's pretty obvious what's going on.

PHP array indices act as hash tables, so they are case sensitive.

In your client side js you set the request header as `'X-Proxy-URL':`, however, in your server-side php you check for `'X-Proxy-Url'`, notice the URL vs Url part.